# How to save compiled document on Desktop using C# Selenium

Tags: selenium, webdriver, c#, visualstudio

Using Selenium WebDriver with C# in VS 2010, I compiled a document using automation and then I want to save the file on my desktop. During automation a new window is popping up to "save or open file". Is there any code available in C# Selenium to manipulate this dialog popup?

Comment: The simple answer is no, but there are workarounds such as Alexey's answer below, or using different application automation frameworks to handle the prompts.

Answer (score 2):

Use profile setting for browsers:

```
firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","text/csv");
```

Browser initialize

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","text/csv");
IWebDriver webDriver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

Comment: Can you give provide more detailed answer        Thanks in advance

Comment: I've added some details to my answer